# For linear modeling, should categorical predictors be factors or characters?

Tags: r, linear-regression

In my data frame i have several mutually exclusive categorical predictors. I have turned them into character vectors (i.e. machine type A,B,C....). Will this work for linear modeling?

Comment: Yes it will work. R's linear modelling functions will coerce them to factors automatically. In `help('lm')` follow the link [`model.matrix`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/model.matrix.html) to read in section Details *"Any character variables are coerced to factors. "*

Comment: thank you, but just so I understand. When I created the DF, I manually converted them to characters. Are you saying that when I run the LM, these same elements, that have been manually converted to characters are then converted back to factors for the running of the LM? If so, does it automatically assume that they have ordered levels?

Comment: I think you can try is.ordered(df$variable) in order to see if it is ordered or not. Should give you either TRUE or FALSE

Comment: If they are character variables they will be converted to factors by the `model.matrix` code but they will still be characters in the data set. As for ordered levels, factors are internally represented as consecutive integers starting at 1. `?ordered()` factors are a different thing. I don't know if this answers the question. Can you give a (small) data example?